# set jqGrid page before url is called

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am looking for a way to set the page of a jqGrid to x...

My use case is someone is using my grid...
They click on a patient to edit that patient (I am not using jqGrids modal edit screen... to many modal windows already)...

When the save what they did to that patient, I want to redirect the browser back to the screen where they clicked on that patient, and back to the SAME PAGE...

The thing to keep in mind.

I am using asp.net MVC4.  I call the first page via an action method.  The url variable of my grid is another action in the same controller.  That action is what I send my page and row variables down to.  I am sure that this can be done, However, I have no idea of how to achieve it.  So far I have tried to set the page variable and rows variable in my document.ready before I call the jqGrid...

```
            tbl.jqGrid({
                loadBeforeSend: function () {
                    page: pageFromTemp;
                    rows: rowFromTemp
                }
            });
```

basically I have tried different ways to do it.  The above is just one of them.
I have tried to reload the grid in the document.ready.  But that doesn't make any sense.  Why reload the grid when you haven't given it any of the parameters it needs...

I have tried to set the variable in the beforeRequest event.  I have a function that I try and set it in...

```
            beforeRequest: function () {
                if ((rowFromTemp != "") && (pageFromTemp != "")) {
                    $(this).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: pageFromTemp, rowNum: rowFromTemp, url: '/Encounters/GetAjaxPagedGridData/' }]);
                    //$.extend($(this).setGridParam({ page: pageFromTemp })),
                    //$.extend($(this).setGridParam({ rowNum: rowFromTemp })),
                    //$.extend($(this).setGridParam({ url: '/Encounters/GetAjaxPagedGridData/' }))
                    //$.trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: pageFromTemp, rowNum: rowFromTemp, url: '/Encounters/GetAjaxPagedGridData/'}]);
                }
            },
```

But that doesn't work either.  I am obviously missing something.  What am I doing wrong...

**Got it to change to the right page using loadComplete and $("frTable").trigger({})**

But now I am getting a flashing Loading screen which indicates to me that it is still loading the data...
If I set a breakpoint in my code, I can confirm that it is loading the data.  I am not doing something right here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Load the grid in document ready, have it's datatype set to `local`, have it's url unassigned, and have it hidden.  When you want to have it load, trigger the load after setting the parameters and then show it to the user.